# Send an e-mail if a cell value meets a given criterion

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a scoreboard automation process using Google Sheets, but I've come up with a little problem. I tried searching here but the question has been treated in a unclear way to me.

What am I trying to do is quite simple:

**I want an automatic e-mail to be sent to a specific person IF cell value > X** (threshold). I already know I need to use Google Apps Script for that, but I haven't found much interesting code lying around yet so I was wondering if you guys had an idea how that would work?

I tried something based on this thread with no success: [How do I make a Google Sheet script send an email when a specific cell's value changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951623/how-do-i-make-a-google-sheet-script-send-an-email-when-a-specific-cells-value-c)

Comment: The answer in that thread is very thorough - why hasn't that worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

@Yvan1401,
You can use a script like this along with an installable trigger like onEdit or onChange to accomplish what you wish.  To set up the installable trigger follow the steps below (found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers)):

1. From the script editor, choose Resources > Current project's
   triggers.
2. Click the link that says: No triggers set up. Click here to add one
   now.
3. Under Run, select the name of function you want to trigger. Under
   Events, select From spreadsheet.
4. Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create (e.g. on
   Change or on Edit trigger).
5. Optionally, click Notifications to configure how and when you will
   be contacted by email if your triggered function fails.
6. Click Save.

Please see comments in code for portions to change.

```
function SendEmail() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  //Change as needed

  if(sheet.getRange(5,1).getValue()>10){      //change row and column in get range to match what you need
    MailApp.sendEmail("xxxxxcxxx@gmail.com", "subject", "message");
  }
}
```

Comment: Be careful that every edit doesn't ping an email and you constrain it to only send if the value you are looking at is the one that has been changed or you record that an email has already been sent.

Comment: Great point @Jonathon!  To accomplish this say you only wanted 1 email per day you could add and additional if condition which would look at another cell and compare the date to today.  if the cell is blank or the date is less than today then the email could be sent if not then skip sending the email!

Comment: Thank you so much for this very precisely described formula, nevertheless, I can't seem to make it work. I don't get any errors but it's like it's the script gets run and then the condition does not get fulfilled although i checked the sheet name, row and colum are appropriate, the destination mail is appropriate and I set the threshold to 0.50. 

Given the value is 0.57 within the cell, I'm guessing it should have triggered or am I missing something I should have changed additionaly?

Comment: Transcript shows clear execution it seems.
[16-03-24 06:34:18:376 PDT] Starting execution
[16-03-24 06:34:18:382 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getUi() [0 seconds]
[16-03-24 06:34:18:382 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActive() [0 seconds]
[16-03-24 06:34:18:430 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Scoreboard]) [0.047 seconds]
[16-03-24 06:34:18:430 PDT] Sheet.getRange([5, 22]) [0 seconds]
[16-03-24 06:34:18:504 PDT] Range.getValue() [0.073 seconds]
[16-03-24 06:34:18:505 PDT] Execution succeeded [0.123 seconds total runtime]

Comment: Problem solved ! The cell I was referencing was a result of a formula, not a hardvalue. It appears the cell must be a hardvalue so it can be read by the script ! Thank you for help :)

Comment: Actually onEdit triggers can't send email can they?

Comment: Not the simple trigger variety!

Comment: Currently this is what I have set up: IF row 2, column 25 and everything in that area changes, THEN SENDMAIL to.... Manually running the code works, but it doesn't do it automatically yet contrary to what I thought !

`function SendEmail() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = file.getSheetByName("Scoreboard");  //Change as needed

  if(sheet.getRange(2,25,1000,1000).getValue()>0,50){      //change row and column in get range to match what you need
    MailApp.sendEmail("ivan@********.com", "mail message content");
  }
}`

Comment: needless to specify, my OnChange trigger is indeed active !

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendMail() {
  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Scoreboard').getRange('AL2:AL1000').getValue()<2.70) return;
  MailApp.sendEmail("yvan@********.com", "******** new potential candidate available ! ", "Dear ****, a new candidate with strong potential is available for due dil !", {
        name: "SOURCE NAME"
    });
}
```

Here is an example of code that works the best and is the shortest. The thing is, I want it to scan only the cells that has changed (updated) within the column in question and not the old responses (data source is a form). What do you think i should do ? Because i don't want to erase the previous response within the same column.

edit: I use an "onChange" trigger.